# Ngx mask and ngx formly - label not floating when initial input value is set

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ngx-formly, ngx-mask

#### The Problem

I have an Angular app (using the standalone API) that uses ngx-formly for creating forms. I am currently adding ngx-mask to be used in masking user input. I have created a custom ngx-formly component type that implements ngx-mask called 'masked-input'. This component type is simply a `mat-form-field` with a `mat-label` and an `input` (which uses the `MatInput` class).

Everything seems to work as expected until I set an initial value with `defaultValue`. When I have this set, the label and value will be overlapping like the following example:
[image: label and value overlapping]

Clicking the input will cause the label to behave normally again.

#### What I've Tried

**Change detection**
Initially felt like a change detection issue. I've tried changing detection strategy to `OnPush` and virtually no change. I've also tried calling `markForCheck()` and `detectChanges()` at various points in the component's lifecycle to no avail. I tried wrapping `markForCheck()` in a `setTimeout` with a 0 second delay in my `ngOnInit()` which actually worked! Though, this feels like a hack and is not a solution I would like to actually ship.

**Input attributes**
I've tried removing and adding attributes on the `input` element to see where exactly it breaks. *The issue begins the moment I add the `mask` attribute*. I also played around with the `value` attribute a bit. I found that I could provide it with a default value of just a space, `value=" "`, and that would also cause the problem to go away. Though, again this feels like a hack and not something I feel comfortable shipping if there is a better way.

**provideAnimations()**
I noticed while playing around with the StackBlitz demo that the label will behave normally if I remove the call to provideAnimations() in the bootstrapApplication() call, though I would begin to get a ton of errors in the console. Maybe that is at least a clue?

#### Code & Environment

I have the following packages installed:

```
"@angular-architects/module-federation": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
"@ngx-formly/core": "^6.1.8",
"@ngx-formly/material": "^6.2.2",
"ngx-mask": "^16.4.2",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.13.0"
```

Though, I was able to reproduce with more up to date package versions. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-u7zpzf?file=src%2Fmain.ts

My system is quite large, but the basic rundown is the following:

1. Client application makes request to backend for component configurations
2. Client application then utilizes custom libraries to create form components from those configurations, populate data if there is any, and apply mask

My Formly component type utilizes the form-field wrapper and looks like:

```
{
  name: 'masked-input',
  component: MaskedInputTypeComponent,
  wrappers: ['form-field']
}
```

My component code looks similar to the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'masked-input',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatInputModule,
    NgxMaskDirective,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormlyModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    <input
      matInput
      [formControl]="formControl"
      [formlyAttributes]="field"
      mask="{{this.mask}}"
      [patterns]="this.patterns ?? null"
      thousandSeparator="{{this.thousandSeparator ?? ' '}}"
      prefix="{{this.prefix ?? null}}"
      suffix="{{this.suffix ?? null}}"
      separatorLimit="{{this.separatorLimit ?? null}}"
      [hiddenInput]="this.hiddenInput ? this.hiddenInput : undefined"
      [dropSpecialCharacters]="this.dropSpecialCharacters ?? true"
      [showMaskTyped]="this.showMaskTyped ?? false"
      [allowNegativeNumbers]="this.allowNegativeNumbers ?? false"
      [placeHolderCharacter]="this.placeHolderCharacter ?? '_'"
      [clearIfNotMatch]="this.clearIfNotMatch ?? false"
      [leadZero]="this.leadZero ?? false"
      [leadZeroDateTime]="this.leadZeroDateTime ?? false"
      [specialCharacters]="this.specialCharacters ?? ['-','/','(',')','.',':',' ','+',',','@','[',']']"
    >
  `
})
export class MaskedInputTypeComponent
  extends FieldType<FieldTypeConfig> implements OnInit {
  label: string;
  mask: string | undefined;
  specialCharacters: string[] | undefined;
  dropSpecialCharacters: boolean | undefined;
  prefix: string | undefined;
  suffix: string | undefined;
  showMaskTyped: boolean | undefined;
  allowNegativeNumbers: boolean | undefined;
  placeHolderCharacter: string | undefined;
  clearIfNotMatch: boolean | undefined;
  thousandSeparator: string | undefined;
  leadZero: boolean | undefined;
  leadZeroDateTime: boolean | undefined;
  separatorLimit: number | undefined;
  hiddenInput: boolean | undefined;
  patterns: IMaskPatterns | undefined;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const maskConfig: IMaskConfig | undefined = this.props['maskConfig'] as IMaskConfig | undefined;
    if (maskConfig) {
      this.mask = maskConfig.mask;
      this.specialCharacters = maskConfig.specialCharacters;
      this.dropSpecialCharacters = maskConfig.dropSpecialCharacters;
      this.prefix = maskConfig.prefix;
      this.suffix = maskConfig.suffix;
      this.showMaskTyped = maskConfig.showMaskTyped;
      this.allowNegativeNumbers = maskConfig.allowNegativeNumbers;
      this.placeHolderCharacter = maskConfig.placeHolderCharacter;
      this.clearIfNotMatch = maskConfig.clearIfNotMatch;
      this.thousandSeparator = maskConfig.thousandSeparator;
      this.leadZero = maskConfig.leadZero;
      this.leadZeroDateTime = maskConfig.leadZeroDateTime;
      this.separatorLimit = maskConfig.separatorLimit
      this.hiddenInput = maskConfig.hiddenInput;
      this.patterns = maskConfig.patterns as IMaskPatterns;
    }
    this.label = this.props['label'] as string;
  }
}
```

### Update

I was able to create a reproduceable example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-u7zpzf?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 1):

In the template for your custom input component, add the following attribute to the `input`:

`value="{{this.formControl.value}}"`

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3uyvuy?file=src%2Ftest-comp%2Ftest-comp.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

I went through the docs of `FormFieldModule` there under `MatFormField` component  I saw this property.

> **@Input()**
> **floatLabel: FloatLabelType**
> Whether the label should always float or float as the user types.

Where it has two values, `always` seems to be for your scenario!

```
export type FloatLabelType = 'always' | 'auto';
```

if you want the float to happen sometimes, you can maintain a variable to toggle this functionality, this might help with your issue!

code

```
<p>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" [floatLabel]="'always'">
    <mat-label>Fill form field</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder" />
    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/k3gmnt?file=src%2Fexample%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the case that the initial value is deleted, I would not want the input label to continue floating which setting `floatLabel` to 'always' would cause. And then if I get into the business of toggling `floatLabel` between 'always' and 'auto', it feels that one of my hacky solutions in the question would be simpler.

Comment: @JonathanMcDonnell No issues!

Comment: @JonathanMcDonnell Please share a basic stackblitz where it happens, not all events are required just the minimal settings to make the issue occour!

Comment: @NaremMurali I'm trying to produce one now

Comment: @NaremMurali I've updated my original question with a reproduceable example